# ArcObjects spatial selection on a newly created shapefile not working

Tags: vb.net, selection, polygon, spatial

I have some VB.NET code which finds all touching polygons using a spatial selection on a shapefile. The code works perfectly when I run it by itself on an existing shapefile, but if the shapefile is previously created in the same program run, the spatial selection never finds any touching polygons. I have even tried creating a new shapefile by copying all the files that it is is made up of (shp, dbf etc) from the one just created but the spatial select doesn't work on that one either. Is there something I should be releasing before I run the select?

Comment: It will help others to understand the problem better if you can post the relevant code snippets from your trial.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem, the solution was to recreate the spatial index on the newly created file. It seems that the one created during the insert process was in some way corrupt. I have also found that the spatial index on a shapefile which has only had it's attributes updated will cause HRESULT E_FAIL COM errors on the NextFeature call after a spatial select is performed